# Prove that if $F : A \rightarrow B$ and $F^{-1}$ is a function, then $F$ is Injective

Tags: proof-writing, proof-verification

Statement: if $F : A \rightarrow B$ and $F^{-1}$ is a function, then $F$ is $1-1$
Proof: If $F$ is not $1-1$, then there exist $x_{1}, x_{2} \in A$ where $x_{1} \neq x_{2}$ and $F(x_{1}) = F(x_{2})$. Therefore, $F^{-1}(y) \neq F^{-1}(y)$, so $F^{-1}$ is not a function. By contraposition, if $F : A \rightarrow B$ and $F^{-1}$ is a function, then $F$ is $1-1$. $\square$

Is my proof valid?

Comment: What os $F^{-1}$ in the first place if $F$ is not at least 1-1?

Comment: Don't say $1-1$. That can be easily confused. Say one-to-one, or better yet, that there is a one-to-one correspondence between the domain and the image of $f$, or best of all, say that $f$ is *injective*.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Functions are binary relations and binary relations always have inverses (switch $(a,b)$ with $(b,a)$ to get the inverse relation).

Comment: @Adrian Your proof is ok, but you never say what $y$ is. You need to either specify that $F(x_1)=y=F(x_2)$ or bound $y$ and say $\exists y\in B(F^{-1}(y)\neq F^{-1}(y))$.

Comment: @GitGud That's one way to put it, but then I assume the proof requires a slightly different presentation for my taste ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof has the right idea (it is 'valid'), but the phrasing could be better, and if I were grading this, I would not give you full marks for "Therefore, $F^{-1}(y) \neq F^{-1}(y)$". Here's how I would do it:

Assume that $F$ is not injective. Then there exist $x_1, x_2 \in A$, such that $x_1 \neq x_2$ and $F(x_1) = F(x_2) = y \in B$. Thus, we would have $F^{-1}(y) = x_1, F^{-1}(y) = x_2$. As a function cannot map an element of its domain to more than one element of its range, this means that $F^{-1}$ would not be a function. But $F^{-1}$ is a function, so our assumption that $F$ is not injective must be false. Therefore, $F$ is injective.